# When is chrome.bookmarks.onChildrenReordered fired?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In Chrome extensions, it seems that whenever a bookmark is moved (to the same folder or not), the [chrome.bookmarks.onMoved](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks#event-onMoved) event will get fired, but not [chrome.bookmarks.onChildrenReordered](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks#event-onChildrenReordered). So when would the latter ever get fired?

Comment: As the documentation says when "sorted in the UI" via `...` menu in the top right corner.

Comment: I just tried moving a bookmark from the menu -> Bookmarks, and only the onMoved event got called. Also tried through the Bookmark Manager and on the bookmark bar and it's the same thing.

Comment: That's not what my comment says... At least I thought I was clear.  https://puu.sh/FigRI/adbdcc1afd.png

Comment: You said "via `...` menu in the top right corner": I was looking at the menu in Chrome's main window. After your latest comment, once again I looked there and didn't see a Sort by name option. But I found the option in the _Bookmark manager_'s menu, and that triggers the onChildrenReordered event. Thanks!